# AJAX передает пустой $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Всем доброго дня!

Вызываю из success AJAX`а функции call() функцию saving(msg), с передачей результата первой функции(call), а на выходе(success) второй функции(saving()) $_POST пустой
Вызов функций

```js
function saving(msg){
    var res=msg;
    //$('#res').html(res);            <-----Вот тут передаваемые данные еще есть
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/wp-content/themes/II/php/saving.php',
        data: res,
        success: function(data){            
            $('#res').html(data);   //<-----А вот тут уже нет
        },
        error:  function(xhr, str){
            alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);//Но эта ошибка не вылезает
        }
    });
    }
    function call() {
    var msg   = $('form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/wp-content/themes/II/php/res.php',
        data: msg,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#results').html(data);
            saving(data);
        },
        error:  function(xhr, str){
            alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
        }
    });     
}
```

При чем во вторую функцию, saving, все приходит как надо. Если это важно то туда приходит достаточно большая (250 строчек) HTML разметка.
PHP второй функции:

```php
<?php
echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Вывод DOM:

```html
<div id="res">
    <pre>Array
    (
    )
    </pre>
</div>
```

Вот почему вывод из PHP пустой?

Comment: `data: res,` если заменить на  `data: {result: res},` ?

Comment: @arch, перепишите это ответом, сработало)))